# Stdlib itoa function

Tags: c, standards, libc

I searched on internet and saw a lot of code that uses itoa() function & they claimed that this function is in stdlib.h

I'm using 2 versions of GCC right now:

1. (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4))
2. (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

and both of them does not have itoa() function (I compile the program & error: undefined reference to `itoa').

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`itoa()` isn't in standard C - `snprintf()` is the function to use in its place (at least it's probably the simplest change to make).

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) gives you an explanation: it's a non standard function, but compilers often provide it through the header `<stdlib.h>` while in non-conforming mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/) is good article regarding this problem starting from phrase "How do I use itoa() with GCC?". Article also provides several itoa() implementations with even performance comparison, please take a look.

Comment: Link is dead now